# get SUM of another row of GROUP BY'd rows

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sum

I have this table:

[image: table]

This selection is is duplicated many times for different var_lines (which pretty much work as one row of data, or respondent for a survey) and set_codes (different survey codes).

With this query:

```
SELECT
    *, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
    `data`
WHERE
    `var_name` = 'GND.NEWS.INT'
AND(
    `set_code` = 'BAN11A-GND'
    OR `set_code` = 'BAN09A-GND'
    OR `set_code` = 'ALG11A-GND'
)
AND `country_id` = '5'
GROUP BY
    `data_content`,
    `set_code`
ORDER BY
    `set_code`,
    `data_content`
```

The query basically counts the number of answers for a specific question. Then groups them survey (set_code).

What I need is for each of the grouped `data_content` answers for GND.NEWS.INT to also show the SUM of all the corresponding GND_WT with the same var_line.

For example if I had this:

```
data_id    data_content    var_name    var_line
1          2               GND.NEW.INT 1
2          1.4             GND_WT      1
3          2               GND.NEW.INT 2
4          1.6             GND_WT      2
5          3               GND.NEW.INT 3
6          0.6             GND_WT      3
```

I would get something like this:

```
data_id    data_content    var_name      var_line   total   weight
1          2               GND.NEW.INT   1          2       3
5          3               GND.NEW.INT   3          1       0.6
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements are not exactly clear, but I think the following gives you what you want:

```
select d1.data_id,
  d1.data_content,
  d1.var_name,
  d1.var_line,
  t.total,
  w.weight
from data d1
inner join
(
  select data_content,
    count(data_content) Total
  from data
  group by data_content
) t
  on d1.data_content = t.data_content
inner join
(
  select var_line,
    sum(case when var_name = 'GND_WT' then data_content end) weight
  from data
  group by var_line
) w
  on d1.var_line = w.var_line
where d1.var_name = 'GND.NEW.INT'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0ecd/17)

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for that. It sort of works but it doesn't seem to group by data_content (the answer) so I can't see how many people have answered that specific answer. Cheers.

Comment: @pocketcup the first subquery groups by the data_content field, is that not what you want?

Comment: Yeah but in the sqlFiddle the rows with data_content = 2 show as two separate rows. I need them as 1 with the totals and weight SUM'd/added together. Cheers.

Comment: @pocketcup then which result do you want if there are two? you have to decide which one you want to return.

Comment: @pocketcup if you want to return only the first, then you can wrap the result in a sub-query -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0ecd/31

Comment: That's just what I was after. Cheers bluefeet.

Answer (score 1):

This Query can be suitable for your specific example:

```
select st.data_id, 
    st.data_content, 
    st.var_name, 
    st.var_line, 
    count(st.data_id) as total,
    sum(st1.data_content) as weight
from data st
left join data st1 on st1.var_name = 'GND_WT' AND st1.var_line=st.var_line
where st.var_name='GND.NEW.INT'
group by st.data_content
```

Regards,

Luis.

Comment: Hi Luis. Thanks for that. I changed stackover1 for my table name but it just runs forever in navicat with not results.

Comment: @pocketcup sorry I pasted with my test table's name, you can recheck with that change